# Rest Endpoints Stopped working after Drupal Upgrade from Drupal Version 8.6.10 to Drupal Version 9.5.9

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

We recently upgrade from Drupal Version 8.6.10 to Drupal Version 9.5.9. After the upgrade we faced bunch of issues. Current primary issue is an api endpoint of the format "getYzMetadata" stopped working. I tried to search for it under Structure > views but couldn't find it.

In addition to this other api endpoints started giving 404 when accessed from an microservices in ECS. It works fine when i am doing curl on the drupal server, and any other ec2 instance in same region/vpc .

Everything is in AWS EC2. I compared old and new httpd.conf , securitygroup mappings and vpc mapping everything is unchanged.

I am new to drupal but have decent experience with devops and aws.

Other info as follows

[image]